# What is this discoloration in my clothes dryer drum?

Tags: dryer, samsung

I am trying to find out why there is like a burn mark inside my dryer. Can anyone help and tell me what may be causing it?

[image: Clothes dryer drum]

Comment: Is this a new dryer and how long has the discoloration been there?

Answer (score 1):

Your heating element would be behind that grill so that discoloration could very well be from a loose connection that's overheating or an element mounting bracket loose and allowing the element to get too close to the back. Is this a new dryer and how long has the discoloration been there?

This is something that should be checked either by you,if it's within your skillset, or a pro.

Comment: @isherwood  My dryer's element is behind the drum and I've replace a number of them behind and under the drum.

Comment: There are many possibilities, such as a brief lint fire that quickly burnt out, or a heating element that briefly contacted the case, creating a spark. How does it smell? Did a breaker trip? Is the dryer working well? Has this happened more than once?